# How to randomly replace elements of list with another list elements?

Tags: python, list, random, replace

```
x_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
t_list = ['z', 'y', 'u']
```

I want replace elements of `t_list` with elements of `x_list`, "randomly". I researched and I tried something but `replace()` didn't work for lists. For example; `x_new0 = ['a', 'z', 'c', 'y', 'u]`, `x_new1 = ['z', 'y', 'c', 'd','u']`. How can I do this?

Comment: You can assign element directly, e.g., `x_list[2] = t_list[0]`

Comment: Is it important that a) All the elements of `t_list` are included in the new list, and b) That those elements are in order?

Comment: Can you please show your attempts? What have tried? What didn't work? Can you provide a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: Is this by position or value? If you had another `a` in `x_list` and it got replaced with `z` - do all values get replaced by `z`? If the length of the two lists are the same - is a straight replacement a correct answer. What if there's less elements in `x` than `t`... Do the elements of `t` have to appear in order in `x`... etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `numpy.random.choice` to randomly select elements where you want the replacements to occur in the original list. Then `zip` those indexes against the values you want to use for the substitution and apply the replacements.

```
from numpy.random import choice

def swap_elements(x, t):
    new_x = x[:]
    for idx, value in zip(choice(range(len(x)), size=len(t), replace=False), t_list):
        new_x[idx] = value
    return new_x
```

Example usage

```
>>> x_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> t_list = ['z', 'y', 'u']
>>> swap_elements(x_list, t_list)
['y', 'u', 'z', 'd', 'e']
>>> swap_elements(x_list, t_list)
['y', 'b', 'z', 'u', 'e']
>>> swap_elements(x_list, t_list)
['y', 'b', 'z', 'u', 'e']
>>> swap_elements(x_list, t_list)
['a', 'u', 'z', 'y', 'e']
```

Comment: The t_list in swap_elements(x,t) is that supposed to be just t? or must you pass the original t_list?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `random` module and use the `random.randint()` method to generate a random number between 1 and 100 as a heads and tails coin toss to decide whether to replace the value or not and then use the `random.choice()` method on the 2nd list to return a random element of the list

```
import random

first = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
second = ['z', 'y', 'u']

print(first)

for index, x in enumerate(first):
    if random.randint(0, 1):
        first[index] = random.choice(second)

print(first)

First run stdout:
>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>> ['y', 'z', 'u', 'y', 'y']

Second run stdout:
>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>> ['a', 'u', 'c', 'u', 'y']
```

Comment: Its replacing all the elements of first list, might he don't want that @AK47

Comment: It's only replacing all of the elements if the 'heads and tails' toss returns true each time

Comment: This allows duplicate replacements

Comment: He never specified that he didnt want duplicates, and allowing for duplicates means the solution is more 'random' since theres more possible results

Comment: And also since his 2nd list is smaller than the first list

Comment: Any reason to not use `random.choice([0, 1])` (or True/False) instead of `random.randint(0, 100) > 50` ?

Comment: yes, its replacing all elements of first list. I didn't want this. 2nd list has 3 element, so in 1st list, it should replace for 3 elements

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a random index of one list, and a random index of the other list and take the value at the index of one and place it at the index of the other. For example:

```
from random import randint

a = [1 ,2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]

RandomIndexA = randint(0, len(a) - 1)
RandomIndexB = randint(0, len(b) - 1)

a[RandomIndexA] = b[RandomIndexB]
```

Alternatively, you could only calculate one random index and then randomly choose an element from the other list using `random.choice(b)` for example:

```
from random import randint, choice

a = [1 ,2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]

RandomIndex = randint(0, len(a) - 1)

a[RandomIndex] = choice(b)
```